# How would you program Pascal's triangle in R?

Tags: r, math, combinatorics

I am reading about programming, and one exercise involved programming Pascal's triangle in R.  My first idea was to make a list and then append things to it, but that didn't work too well.  Then I thought of starting with a vector, and making a list out of that, at the end.  Then I thought of making a matrix, and making a list out of that at the end.

Not sure which way to even approach this.

Comment: The most convenient storing structure would probably depend on the algorithm that you want to use. After all, R does have a `choose` function.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is one solution on [Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Pascal's_triangle#R):

```
pascalTriangle <- function(h) {
  for(i in 0:(h-1)) {
    s <- ""
    for(k in 0:(h-i)) s <- paste(s, "  ", sep="")
    for(j in 0:i) {
      s <- paste(s, sprintf("%3d ", choose(i, j)), sep="")
    }
    print(s)
  }
}
```

I would store this in a list if I was developing it myself, since that is the most natural data structure to handle variable length rows.  But you really would need to clarify a use case before making that decision.  Are you intending on doing analysis on the data after it has been generated?

*Edit:*

Here is the Rosetta solution rewritten with less looping, and storing the results as a list:

```
pascalTriangle <- function(h) {
  lapply(0:h, function(i) choose(i, 0:i))
}
```

Comment: I always check Rosetta Code first for something as generic as that.  Although the solutions usually aren't optimal, they can help as a first step.

Comment: `pascalTriangle <- function(h) {
  sapply(0:h, function(i) choose(0:h, i))
}` returns the triangle as a square matrix

Answer (score 4):

using a property of the Pascal triangle:

```
x <- 1
print(x)
for (i in 1:10) { x <- c(0, x) + c(x, 0); print(x) }
```

I suppose this code is very fast.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution avoiding loops (R is not a big fan of loops):

```
sapply(1:10, function(n) sapply(0:n, function(k) choose(n, k)))
```

You can replace `1:10` with any vector, even noncontiguous ones:

```
R> sapply(c(5, 10), function(n) sapply(0:n, function(k) choose(n, k)))
[[1]]
[1]  1  5 10 10  5  1

[[2]]
[1]   1  10  45 120 210 252 210 120  45  10   1
```