# Open-CL and pascal triangle

Tags: c++, c, opencl

What would be an approach for a kernel for solving pascals triangle if we only need the nth row?

I don't see any parallelization tasks. The only thing I can see is probably the parallelization of the addition from ith row to ith+1. What are your thoughts?

Comment: This may be of use, perhaps an algorithm there can be parallelized without having to calculate every previous row: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15580291/how-to-efficiently-calculate-a-row-in-pascals-triangle

Comment: Are you planning to parallely compute many rows or just 1 of them? Do you need the full row or just one value or that row? There are many approaches, some of them more optimal.

Comment: I am looking for one output which is the final row of the provided input n. I know I can compute them using the binomial coefficient but would prefer not to. I am looking for a way to dispatch just one dispatch queue.