# Binomial coefficient pseudo code

Tags: algorithm, pseudocode

1.I just understood by calculating one binomial coefficient example step by step. but when it comes to pseudo code, I am a little bit confused. especially this part for(j=minimum(i,k); j>=0; j--).
and what else I understood is that n is the size of column, and k is the size of row. I want to know if I understood right or not.

```
int bin2(int n, int k)
{
    index i, j;

    int B[0...k];

    for(i = 0;i <= n; i++)
    {
        for(j = minimum(i, k); j >= 0; j--)
        {
            if(j == 0 || j == i)
                B[j]=1;
            else 
                B[j] = B[j - 1] + B[j]; 
        }
    }

    return B[n][k];
}
```

Comment: `B[n][k]` doesn't make sense if `B` is a 1-dimensional array. If you are trying to build up Pascal's triangle you need a 2-d array.

Comment: Also -- calculating a binomial coefficient by calculating all of Pascal's triangle above it (which you seem to be trying to do) is inefficient. There are recurrences which allow one to calculate the nth row without calculating previous rows. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/15580291/4996248

Answer (score 0):

That's a c style loop. What it says is iterate with j from minimum(i,k) down to 0 (or as long as j>=0 ) in steps of -1 (j-- decreases j by 1).

The return should read B[k] because it's a 1-dimensional array.