# Get column and row from Trinomial triangle

Tags: python, combinatorics

What algorithm could I use that automatically retrieves the value at a particular column and row of the Trinomial triangle, without actually generating the entire triangle? I know there is a way to do it with the standard Pascal's triangle, but I can't figure out how to do it with the trinomial triangle. Preferably, I would like the algorithm in python.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15580291/how-to-efficiently-calculate-a-row-in-pascals-triangle

Comment: Wikipedia has the answer.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trinomial_triangle.  It can be expressed as the sum of two binomial triangle coefficients, which you can compute.