# R: How can I calculate large numbers in n-choose-k?

Tags: r, factorial, exponent

For a class assignment, I need to create a function that calculates n Choose k. I did just that, and it works fine with small numbers (e.g. 6 choose 2), but I'm supposed to get it work with 200 choose 50, where it naturally doesn't.
The answer is too large and R outputs NaN or Inf, saying:

```
> q5(200, 50)
[1] "NaN"
Warning message:
In factorial(n) : value out of range in 'gammafn'
```

I tried using logs and exponents, but it doesn't cut it.

```
q5 <- function (n, k) {
  answer <- log(exp( factorial(n) / ( (factorial(k)) * (factorial(n - k)) )))
  paste0(answer)
}
```

Comment: Sure you could do it with Sterling's rule, but it isn't getting the right answers, and I don't have time to figure out why :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2632441/how-would-you-program-pascals-triangle-in-r

Comment: Sterling simply wasn't accurate enough down at that range.

Comment: How is this a duplicate? The way to solve it requires using a forumla to approximate the answer - the so-called "duplicates" do not address it.

Comment: Hello? - Could you mark one of these as "correct"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer to the actual question is that R cannot show numbers it cannot represent, and some of the terms in your equation are too big to represent. So it fails. However there are approximations to factorial that can be used - they work with logarithms which get big a lot slower.

The most famous one, Sterling's approximation, was not accurate enough, but the [Ramanujan's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial#Rate_of_growth_and_approximations_for_large_n) came to the rescue :)

```
ramanujan <- function(n){
  n*log(n) - n + log(n*(1 + 4*n*(1+2*n)))/6 + log(pi)/2
}

nchoosek <- function(n,k){
  factorial(n)/(factorial(k)*factorial(n-k))
} 

bignchoosek <- function(n,k){
  exp(ramanujan(n) - ramanujan(k) - ramanujan(n-k))
}

nchoosek(20,5)
# [1] 15504

bignchoosek(20,5)
# [1] 15504.06


bignchoosek(200,50)
# [1] 4.538584e+47
```

Comment: can you please point me to Ramanujan's work regarding this?

Comment: It is in the wikipedia article on factorials, in the section under approximations.

Comment: Very nice. Above, `nchoosek(200,50)` produces `[1] NaN
Warning message: In factorial(n) : value out of range in 'gammafn'` whereas `bignchoosek(200,50)` performs it as you showed.

Comment: It looks great, we haven't touched on that at all but I don't quite get, why in the second function looks like the formula, but the third is just subtraction?

Comment: because when you take the log of a ratio (division), it turns into subtraction. `log(a/b) = log(a) - log(b)`

Comment: And `log(a/(b*c) = log(a) - (log(b)+log(c)) = log(a) - log(b) - log(c)`

Comment: Right, but is the `ramanujan` function here treated as log when executed?

Comment: Yes. This is because `ramanujan` is a formula for the `log(n!)`, not for `n!`.

Answer (score 3):

The packages for large numbers:

`Brobdingnag` package for "*Very large numbers* in R":
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Brobdingnag/index.html
Paper: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/251996764_Very_large_numbers_in_R_Introducing_package_Brobdingnag

```
library(Brobdingnag)
googol <- as.brob(10)^100 # googol:=10^100
googol
# [1] +exp(230.26) # exponential notation is convenient for very large numbers
```

`gmp` package for multiple Precision Arithmetic (*big integers* and rationals, prime number tests, matrix computation):
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gmp/index.html

Comment: In general this is a good way to approach things, but for this particular problem there are good numerical approximations. Like the approach anyway.

Comment: Why don't you upvote the question? It is a good one I think, and people want to close it.

Comment: @MikeWise, I did.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this too:

```
q5 <- function (n, k) {
  # nchoosek = (n-k+1)(n-k+2)...n / (1.2...k)
  return(prod(sapply(1:k, function(i)(n-k+i)/(i))))
}

q5(200, 50)
#[1] 4.538584e+47
```

or in log domain

```
q5 <- function (n, k) {
  # ln (nchoosek) = ln(n-k+1) + ln(n-k+2) + ...+ ln(n) - ln(1) -ln(2) - ...- ln(k)
  return(exp(sum(sapply(1:k, function(i)(log(n-k+i) - log(i))))))
}
q5(200, 50)
#[1] 4.538584e+47
```

Comment: This is good, like it. Think my answer scales better though. That can turn into a lot of logs.

Comment: or `prod((n:(n-k+1)) / 1:k)` or with logs `sum(log(n:(n-k+1))-log(1:k))`

Answer (score 2):

This solution calculates the complete row of the Pascal triangle:

```
x <- 1
print(x)
for (i in 1:200) { x <- c(0, x) + c(x, 0); print(x) }
x[51]  ### 200 choose 50
## > x[51]
## [1] 4.538584e+47
```

(as I proposed for [How would you program Pascal's triangle in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2632441/how-would-you-program-pascals-triangle-in-r) )
If you want to speed up the code then do not the `print(x)` (output is a relative slow operation).

To put the code in a function we can do

```
nchoosek <- function(n,k) {
    x <- 1
    for (i in 1:n) x <- c(0, x) + c(x, 0)
    x[k+1]  ### n choose k
} 

nchoosek(200, 50)    ### testing the function
## [1] 4.538584e+47
```

Here is a more refined version of my function:

```
nchoosek <- function(n, k) {
  if (k==0) return(1)
  if (k+k > n) k <- n-k
  if (k==0) return(1)
  x <- 1
  for (i in 1:k)     x <- c(0, x) + c(x, 0)
  for (i in 1:(n-k)) x <- x + c(0, head(x, -1))
  tail(x, 1)
} 
nchoosek(200, 50)    ### testing the function
## [1] 4.538584e+47
```

Comment: It is quite a nice solution. But it seems a bit like magic the way you have presented it and it is also not clear how to use it. Wrapping it in a function like I did with `nchoosek(n,k)` would help a lot and only add a couple of lines.

Comment: I edited my answer.